# NSTableView Data Source Not Working

Tags: objective-c, macos, sockets

I am trying to populate an NSTableView with an NSArray. I have a view controller, which I have set as my datasource, but every time I run the program, I get this error: `Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`, both of which I have implemented. 
Here is my header:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ChatViewController : NSViewController <NSTableViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView;
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex;

@end
```

And here is my implementation file:

```
#import "ChatViewController.h"
#import "Socket.h"

@interface ChatViewController ()

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTableView *people;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *message;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSButton *send;

@property (strong) Socket *sock;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *recievedText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tableData;

- (void)updateUI;

@end

@implementation ChatViewController

@synthesize sock;
@synthesize recievedText;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self.people setDataSource:self];
        sock = [[Socket alloc] init];
        [sock connectToServerWithIP:@"127.0.0.1" andPort:5001];
        [self updateUI];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)updateUI
{
    [sock sendMessage:@"getPeople"];
    recievedText = [NSString stringWithString:[sock recieveMessage]];
    self.tableData = [recievedText componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.tableData);

    [self.people reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.people);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    return [self.tableData count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return [self.tableData objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

@end
```

`Socket` is a class that I created for opening and closing sockets to a server, which is fully functional. The `tableData` array is populated like a normal array.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at first make your table view delegate and data source of file's owner through xib.

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    if(aTableView == tableViewS)
    {
        if([[aTableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"first"])
        {
            return [self.tableData objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

you need to give identifier name for table column

tableViewS is IBOutlet of table view.

Comment: How do I set the identifier in the xib? Thanks for the answer

Comment: In xib, select table column, go to identify inspector, set the identifier name there.

Answer (score 2):

First of you don't need to declare the methods in your .h file since they are part of the protocol your class is implementing. And also have you really set you data source? Have you done something like this some where?

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: Omg i didn't do that but when I add it it doesn't do anything to change the error and the tableview still doesn't populate.

Comment: Only other thing i can think of is that you redeclare the two protocol methods in your interface declaration in your .h file. You should not do that since it's already part of the protocol your class confirms to. Although i don't think it would prevent your tableview from finding the methods in your class since they are present.

Comment: OMG you are right i had the data source hooked up in the xib and in the code, and it did't work, so I just set the delegate and datasource through the xib and it worked. Also @PR_Singh said that at the beginning of his answer but only now I understand it.